# Étale stack on $\text{Spec}(k)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory, stacks, grothendieck-topology

Let $\mathcal{F}:\text{Ét}(\text{Spec}(k))^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ be an étale presheaf. The étale sheaf condition for the cover $\text{Spec}(l)\rightarrow \text{Spec}(k)$ is
$$\mathcal{F}(k)\cong \text{Eq}\left(\mathcal{F}(l)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(l\otimes_k l)\cong \prod_{\text{Gal}(l/k)}\mathcal{F}(l)\right)$$
which reduces to
$$\mathcal{F}(k)=\mathcal{F}(l)^{\mathrm{Gal}(l/k)}.$$
(Please apologize the notation $\mathcal{F}(k):=\mathcal{F}(\text{Spec}(k))$) I'm trying to understand the analogue condition for $2$-sheaves on $\text{Ét}(k)$. If $\mathcal{F}:\text{Ét}(\text{Spec}(k))^{\mathrm{op}}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$ is an $2$-functor, then the $2$-sheaf condition for $\text{Spec}(l)\rightarrow \text{Spec}(k)$ is
$$\mathcal{F}(k)\cong \lim\left(\mathcal{F}(l)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(l\otimes_k l)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(l\otimes_k l\otimes_k l)\right)\cong
\lim\left(\mathcal{F}(l)\rightarrow \prod_{\text{Gal}(l/k)}\mathcal{F}(l) \rightarrow\prod_{\text{Gal}(l/k)^2}\mathcal{F}(l)\right).$$
I don't know what this limit would be. A guess/hope would be that this limit would be the "Galois invariant"-subcategory of $\mathcal{F}(l)$ n the sense that it would consist of all objects which are invariant under all morphisms $l\rightarrow l$ and something similar for homs, I suposse...

Comment: It’s homotopy fixed points for the Galois action. See the sequence of blog posts starting here: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/08/the-puzzle-of-galois-descent/

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I get lots of "Formula does not parse" in those posts.  For example, in the post you linked, all the math is fine up to "...$L$ of $k$ is equivalent to knowing [Formula does not parse], where $\overline k$ denotes the algebraic closure of $k$".  Another example: of the two centered formulas, the second renders fine, while the first "does not parse".  It might just be me, but it's strange, I read other posts on your blog in the past and this never happened. (FYI, I'm on Firefox 81.0.1 (latest version), under Mac OS).

Comment: @Damiano: that’s a bug in WordPress. It comes and goes and I have no idea what causes it...